# Spring Boot Application Availability (Liveness and Readiness) Returns 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got a Spring Boot application (v2.3.2) and enabled the actuator health group for liveness and readiness:

```yaml
management:
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: false
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
      probes:
        enabled: true
```

And `GET /actuator/health` returns:

```
{
    "groups": [
        "liveness",
        "readiness"
    ],
    "status": "UP"
}
```

According to the documentation, I should also be able to `GET /actuator/health/liveness` and `GET /actuator/health/readiness`, but both return `404`.
Did I miss any configuration or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work

```yaml
management:
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: false
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
      probes:
        enabled: true
      group:
        liveness:
          include: "livenessStateProbeIndicator"
        readiness:
          include: "readinessStateProbeIndicator"
```

it is a workaround due to an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22562)