# Spring boot Kubernetes readyness / liveness probes 404 on local deployment

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I've enabled liveness and readiness endpoints using Spring Boot actuator (v2.6.1)

What I have is the following config:

```
management
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
      probes:
        enabled: true
      group:
        readiness:
          include: readinessStateProbeIndicator
        exploratory:
          include:
            - livenessState
            - readinessState
            - ping
          show-details: always
  health:
    enabled: true
    probes:
      livenessstate:
        enabled: true
      readinessstate:
        enabled: true
```

Probably `endpoint.health.enabled`, `endpoint.health.group.explotatory...` are not required but I set it because I've seen it for some working solution, but I don't think there will affect if are not needed.

What I have read, but not in official docs, is that this endpoints are not available in a local deployment (running the application). Is this the reason why I'm getting 404 when I try to call `http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/readiness` and `/actuator/health/liveness` or I'm missing something?

I checked some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194537/spring-application-availability-liveness-and-readiness-returns-404) but it seems `management.health.enabled` has been deprecated and `management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled` should be enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the setting I was looking for, and it works fine on localhost:

```
endpoint:
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: true
      enabled: true
```